# Connecting Net-Beans to SQLSERVER using jTDS

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, sqlconnection, jtds

I am new in databases and now need a little of your help. I am trying to connect my NetBeans with SQL SERVER using jTDS. MY code is following which I have just copied from a blog. I am getting too many errors

I have already enabled TCP port, SQL SERVER browser,disabled Windows firewall.

```
   /**
 * ConnectMSSQL.java
 */
package com.javaworkspace.connectmssql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ConnectMSSQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(
                            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;company;selectMethod=cursor",
                            "username", "password");

            System.out.println("DATABASE NAME IS:"
                    + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEEDETAILS");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NAME:"
                        + resultSet.getString("EMPNAME"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error:

[image]

I know I am expecting too much from you but it would be really helpful for me

Comment: Looks like your server is not running or is listening on a different port.

Comment: Is running the SQL server?

Comment: No one here to help !!!!!!!!!!